# Words in the Kagoshima dialect

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonology

Using [this Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagoshima_dialect#Sonorant_gliding), I learnt that words in Standard Japanese may encounter something called **sonorant gliding** while converting to Kagoshima dialect. For what is written here, these are the rules that I gathered:

- This occurs when there is a kana starting with the 'r' consonant not at the start of the word.
- If the kana came before a kana ending in the vowels /a/ or /o/, the former kana changes the /r/ to a /y/ sound, or if no such kana exists, the whole thing becomes い.
- If the kana came before a kana ending in the vowels /i/, /u/ or /e/, the former kana changes the /r/ to a /y/ sound, the former kana becomes い.

Can someone please advise me on any mistakes I have made here?